# Swift addConstraint leads to EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION

Tags: swift, macos, swift3, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I've been playing around with `NSTouchBar` in a macOS application and came up with the following code:

```
func touchBar(_ touchBar: NSTouchBar, makeItemForIdentifier identifier: NSTouchBarItemIdentifier) -> NSTouchBarItem? {
    switch identifier {
    case NSTouchBarItemIdentifier.testItemIdentifier:
        let viewObject = NSView()

        for i in 1...10 {
            let imageWidth: CGFloat = 20;
            let imageHeight: CGFloat = 20;
            let imagePositionTop: CGFloat = 0
            let imagePositionLeft: CGFloat = imageWidth * (CGFloat(i) - 1)

            let imageObject = NSImage(named: "test_image")!
            imageObject.size = NSSize(width: 20, height: 20)
            let imageView = NSImageView(image: imageObject)
            let constraintObject1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: viewObject, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.top, multiplier: 1, constant: imagePositionTop)
            let constraintObject2 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: viewObject, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.left, multiplier: 1, constant: imagePositionLeft)
            let constraintObject3 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.width, multiplier: 0, constant: imageWidth)
            let constraintObject4 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.equal, toItem: imageView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.height, multiplier: 0, constant: imageHeight)

            imageView.addConstraint(constraintObject1)
            imageView.addConstraint(constraintObject2)
            imageView.addConstraint(constraintObject3)
            imageView.addConstraint(constraintObject4)

            viewObject.addSubview(imageView)
        }

        let customViewItem = NSCustomTouchBarItem(identifier: identifier)
        customViewItem.view = viewObject
        return customViewItem
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

When running the application, I get an `EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)`. The cause of this seems to be the calls to `addConstraint`. I've never created constraints manually before, and am relatively new to the swift language.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

@toddg is correct: you must add `imageView` as a subview of `viewObject` **before** you can activate a constraint between the two views. Two views must be in the same view hierarchy if you want to activate a constraint involving both of them.

But you have other problems.

A constraint between two views A and B must be added to a common ancestor of A and B (which may be A or B itself). In your case, since `imageView` is a subview of `viewObject`, that means that any constraint between `imageView` and `viewObject` must be added to `viewObject` (or a superview of `viewObject`). You cannot add the constraint to `imageView`. You can fix this by setting [the `isActive` property](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslayoutconstraint/1527000-isactive) of the constraint to true instead of using `addConstraint`. When you set the `isActive` property to true, the constraint will add itself to the appropriate view.

Also, you're creating a constraint between `imageView.width` and `imageView.width`, which doesn't make sense. If you want to constrain `imageView.width` to a constant, the other item of the constraint should be `nil` with an attribute of [`.notAnAttribute`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/nslayoutattribute/1526923-notanattribute).

Also, you're not setting [`translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsview/1526961-translatesautoresizingmaskintoco) to false, which you need to do if you want to use constraints to set the size and position of the `imageView`.

Anyway, you're using a bunch of old API that makes things harder than necessary. You can make your code correct, and much shorter and simpler, by using an [`NSStackView`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsstackview). `NSStackView` was added in macOS 10.9, and `NSTouchBar` was added in macOS 10.12.2, so there's no reason *not* to use a stack view for this.

```
func touchBar(_ touchBar: NSTouchBar, makeItemForIdentifier identifier: NSTouchBarItemIdentifier) -> NSTouchBarItem? {
    switch identifier {
    case NSTouchBarItemIdentifier.testItemIdentifier:
        let stack = NSStackView()
        stack.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        stack.spacing = 0
        stack.distribution = .fillEqually

        let length = CGFloat(20)

        for _ in 1...10 {
            let imageObject = NSImage(named: "test_image")!
            imageObject.size = NSSize(width: length, height: length)
            let imageView = NSImageView(image: imageObject)
            imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            stack.addArrangedSubview(imageView)
        }

        let customViewItem = NSCustomTouchBarItem(identifier: identifier)
        customViewItem.view = stack
        return customViewItem
    default:
        return nil
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: "You cannot add the constraint to imageView" <-- why not? I mean what's the difference of saying the distance from me to you is 10inches or you saying the distance from you to me is 10inches?

Comment: As I explained, a constraint must be added to a common ancestor of the constraint's constrained views. If `viewObject` is the superview of `imageView`, and the constraint is between `viewObject` and `imageView`, then the constraint must be added to `viewObject` (or a superview of `viewObject`). If you try to add it to `imageView`, you get an error.

Comment: This is spelled out in the [`-[NSView addConstraint:]`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/appkit/nsview/1526969-addconstraint) documentation: “The constraint must involve only views that are within scope of the receiving view. Specifically, any views involved must be either the receiving view itself, or a subview of the receiving view.”

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! Everything works now.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the view before you add the constraints. Try adding the constraints to the viewObject

```
viewObject.addSubview(imageView)
viewObject.addConstraint(constraintObject1)
viewObject.addConstraint(constraintObject2)
viewObject.addConstraint(constraintObject3)
viewObject.addConstraint(constraintObject4)
```

Also, for future reference, you should include all of the text error message.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, this results in the same error. The complete error message is: EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_I386_INVOP, subcode=0x0)

Comment: I've updated my answer. There is usually more information about the error in the console. Press command-shift-c when your application is running (or open it from the menu) to show the console.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @toddg's answer, you should consider using `NSLayoutAnchor` for simple layouts like this.  It simplifies the code.

```
imageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewObject.topAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewObject.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewObject.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
imageView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: viewObject.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
```

This initializes the constraint **AND** activates it in one line of code.  Just be sure to add the `imageView` to the view stack first.

Also, you likely want to set `imageView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`.

You also don't need to set `imageObject.size = NSSize(width: 20, height: 20)` - the constraints will handle that for you.